# Add column to 50M+ records table? Most efficient way?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

I have a table `products` that has over 50M records. I want to track who uploaded given product in my system but simply adding `uploaded_by_id` to such a huge table isn't the solutions I'm looking for. What else than a join table can I create to be able to query for products uploaded by given id in given time range?
`Product.where(uploaded_by_id: @user.id, created_at: time_range)` is what I need to do but I need more efficient way.

Comment: Please explain why adding a column that has explicitly the information you want is *not* the solution you are looking for.

Comment: @GordonLinoff because I cannot lock the table for a long time

Comment: Shutdown the system for a few minutes.  Copy the table into a new location.  Truncate the table, add the column, and insert the table back in.  That should take less than an hour.  And you can test it in advance if the table is being used.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into tools like

- [Soundscloud's Large Hadron Migrator](https://github.com/soundcloud/lhm) or
- [Percona's pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html).

Both tools allow altering tables without locking them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of touching the main table, add another table (Vertical Partitioning).  The new table would have the same `PRIMARY KEY`, but not `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  The new column(s) would go into this table.

Create rows in the new table only when the new column(s) have a value.

When you don't need the new column(s), continue to read only from the old table.

When you also need the new column(s), use `LEFT JOIN`.